# What effect does linearly projecting a state space to another dimension have on the Jacobian?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, nonlinear-system, jacobian

Suppose I have a real vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a real, nonlinear vector-valued function $\sigma(x) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I denote the matrix Jacobian

$$\partial_x \sigma(x)$$

Suppose I have a linear transformation $P: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$. What is the Jacobian of the projected state space with respect to the projected input? In other words, what is

$$\partial_{Px} P\sigma(x)$$

How would I go about calculating this?

Comment: This isn't really well-defined as $P \circ \sigma \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ is a function of a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, not of a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$. To make this well-defined, you need to specify how you think of a "projected input" (which has only $k$ coordinates) as sitting inside $\mathbb{R}^n$ (which has $n$ coordinates) by giving a (probably) linear map $Q \colon \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such as $Q(x_1,\dots,x_k)=(x_1,\dots,x_k,0,\dots,0)$. Then $\partial_x (Q \circ \sigma \circ P) = Q (\partial_x \sigma)(P(x)) P$ using the chain rule.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that P is orthogonal. After reading your comment and thinking, I believe what I really want is exactly what you wrote: $y \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $\partial_y P \sigma(P^{-1}(y))$. Then the chain rule becomes clear.

Comment: @levap if you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You can write down an answer to your own question (this is encouraged on stackexchange) and I'll upvote it. Just note that there is no such a thing $P^{-1}$ as $P \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ so if $k < n$ then $P$ is not invertible. What you probably want is right inverse $Q \colon \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $P(Q(x)) = x$. And in my first comment, I meant to write $P \circ \sigma \circ Q$ and not $Q \circ \sigma \circ P$ (as you project the image of $\sigma$).